# How to make background image change smoothly while hovering a subdiv?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

This is as far as I managed to go.
Background-image is set with inline css on container (is not working otherwise). 
How can I have any kind of smooth transition between the image change?

```js
    function onmouseover(){
        // alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        var element = document.getElementById('conf');
        element.style.backgroundImage = "url('/imgs/jpg/stats.jpg')";
    }
    function onmouseout(){
        // alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        var element = document.getElementById('conf');
        element.style.backgroundImage = "url('/imgs/jpg/welcome_back.jpg')";
    }
```

This code is actually changing the background-image that is already set. This transaction is happening very fast and sharp

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth transaction?"

Comment: Do you make some research? Try this.
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_animate_fading

Comment: Anything but change too sudden and sharp

Comment: it's set as an background-image and not as <img> tag.

Answer (score 1):

background is one of the animatable CSS properties so you can set a transition on it.

This snippet uses the code given in the question with an element with id conf which has a subdiv element on which you can hover. The main thing that has been set is:

```
transition: background-image 1s linear;
```

in conf so the backgrounds change over smoothly.

```js
const conf = document.getElementById('conf');
const subdiv = document.getElementById('subdiv');
subdiv.addEventListener('mouseover', onmouseover);
subdiv.addEventListener('mouseout', onmouseout);

function onmouseover() {
  // alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  var element = document.getElementById('conf');
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300')";
}

function onmouseout() {
  // alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  var element = document.getElementById('conf');
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300')";
}
```

```css
#conf {
  transition: background-image 1s linear;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
}

#subdiv {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conf">
  <div id="subdiv">Hover over me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this only with HTML and CSS using the `transition` property

```css
img {
  position:absolute;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" /><img class="top" src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300" />
```